# URL Rewrite with Special Character

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have an incoming link to my site that is 'incorrect' and I cannot get the incoming link changed so I am having to make a redirect rule for it.

The link points to:
mydomain.tld/search_engin%3C/td

I have tried:

```
RewriteRule ^/search_engin%3C/td$ http://www.osirion.co.za/search_engine_marketing_optimisation/1-about_our_search_engine_marketing_services.htm [NE,R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^/search_engin%3C/td$ http://www.osirion.co.za/search_engine_marketing_optimisation/1-about_our_search_engine_marketing_services.htm [B,R=301,L]
```

(the two above without the $)
Normal Redirect 301 instead of RewriteRule as well.

None of them worked :S

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the regular expression to:

```
`^/search_engin</td$`
```

The `%3C` gets decoded before being put through the rewrite engine. Also, get rid of the leading slash if this rule is in an htaccess file. You don't need the `NE` or `B` flags, but everything else looks fine.

Comment: That (decoding + removing leading /) seems to have worked for the above said rule, but applying the same logic to the below two didnt have the same effect. Now I get a "Internal Server Error" showing on my site:
# The request: /web_h...%3C/h1%3E%3Ch3%3ESectore%3C/h3%3E%3Cp%20class=
RewriteRule ^web_h...</h1><h3>Sectore</h3><p class=$ http://www.osirion.co.za/web_hosting/1-web_hosting.htm [R=301,L]
# The request: web_h...%3C/h1%3E%3Ch3%3EQualifore%3C/h3%3E%3Cp%20class=
RewriteRule ^web_h...</h1><h3>Qualifore</h3><p class=$ http://www.osirion.co.za/web_hosting/1-web_hosting.htm [R=301,L]

Comment: @SupaMonkey You'll need to escape the space: `^web_h...</h1><h3>Sectore</h3><p\ class=$`